Laravel - Job has been attempted too many times
To anyone using Laravel Jobs and Horizon. Sometimes, after the job succeed, the queue tries it again with no reason:
App\Jobs\Job has been attempted too many times. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Queue\\MaxAttemptsExceededException(code: 0): App\\Jobs\\Job has been attempted too many times. at /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/MaxAttemptsExceededException.php:24)
I've tried different Horizon configuration but it continues happening. I saw that you must increate the retry_after param, but still happening.
Does anyone have a solution? It happened to me in several projects.
'defaults' => [
        'supervisor-1' => [
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'queue' => ['default'],
            'balance' => 'auto',
            'autoScalingStrategy' => 'time',
            'maxProcesses' => 1,
            'maxTime' => 0,
            'maxJobs' => 0,
            'memory' => 256,
            'tries' => 1,
            'timeout' => 3600,
            'nice' => 0,
            'retry_after' => 3700,
        ],
    ],`


You can configure directly from the job definition by declaring job variables like:
public $tries = 10; //max execution of job will be 10 times
public $retryAfter = 60; // interval for next job is 60 seconds  
public $timeout = 1200; // Max execution time is 1200 seconds  for this job


I already set the 'tries' => 1, in all the configs. Seems that is retries it randomly
